# Statement based problem for two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with entries in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I have to check which of the following two statements **P** and **Q** are true.

Consider two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with entries in $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the following statements:

**Statement P** If $A$ and $B$ have the same minimal polynomial then $A$ is similar to $B$.

**Statement Q**  If $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then there exist $u\in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $u, Au, \ldots A^{n-1}u$ are linearly independent.

My approach for Statement **Q**. Let $\lambda \neq 0$ be the eigenvalue of $A$ and $u$ be the corresponding eigenvector. Then eigenvalue of the matrix power $A^{n-1}$ will be $\lambda^{n-1}$ with eigenvector $x$. With this information the linear combinations $\alpha_1 u + \alpha_2 Au \ldots +\alpha_n A^{n-1} u = 0$ will imply scalars $\alpha_i = 0$. Which shows that statement Q is true. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Statement P looks falls to me as I know that two similar matrices have same minimal polynomial but reverse may not true. However, I am not able to find out the counter example.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Similar matrices with the same minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454135/similar-matrices-with-the-same-minimal-polynomial)

Comment: Statement $P$ has counterexamples given in the duplicate, and $Q$ you have solved yourself.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't understand your comment. If $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $A^ku$ is necessarily a scalar multiple of $u$. How can $u,Au,\ldots$ be linearly independent?!

Comment: @user1551 I am sorry, I meant the OP should have solved it himself, or searched it himself, since it is also solved in a duplicate here.

Comment: This question is not a complete duplicate of the mentioned question. Statement Q has never been asked and also not given in the link provided. Kindly rethink before closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

The two statements are quite different in nature. Consider first Q, for which your given argument does not seem good (certainly $\alpha_1=\lambda$, $\alpha_2=-1$ and the rest $0$ gives a valid relation: $\lambda u-A u=0$).

With as many (distinct) eigenvalues as the dimension of the vector space, $A$ is always diagonalisable, and we can use coordinates with respect to a basis $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ of eigenvectors (that is, we can express any vector $v$ as $c_1u_1+\cdots+c_nu_n$, and $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ are its coordinates). Statement Q says there is some vector$~v$ such that no nonzero polynomial$~P$ of degree less than $n$ can make $P[A]\cdot v=0$. Now $P[A]$ multiplies the coordinate $c_i$ by $P[\lambda_i]$ (since $P[A]$ multiplies each $u_i$ by $P[\lambda_i]$). So if we take $v$ to have all its coordinates$~c_i$ nonzero, then $P[A]\cdot v=0$ only if $P[\lambda_i]=0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, and we need to show that this cannot happen when $P$ is nonzero of degree less than $n$. But this is just the well known fact that such a polynomial has less than $n$ distinct roots.

For statement P, you are right to guess that it is going to be false; the minimal polynomial will tell you the size of the largest Jordan block for each eigenvalue, while similarity requires that all Jordan block pair up (matching both size and eigenvalue). To get a counterexample, you can either go for the multiplicities of identical blocks, or for the distributions of sizes. The former approach works with only $1\times1$ Jordan blocks (diagonalisable case) and then needs two distinct eigenvalues; it gives you for instance a pair of $3\times3$ diagonal matrices with diagonal entries $(0,0,1)$ respectively $(0,1,1)$; both (projections) have minimal polynomial $X(X-1)$, but they are not similar. The latter approach requires only one eigenvalue, but needs somewhat larger matrices. If the minimal polynomial is $X^2$ (unique eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ with $2\times2$ as largest Jordan block), you can for instance take $4\times4$ matrices with Jordan blocks of sizes $(2,2)$ respectively $(2,1,1)$, which are not similar.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint for statement Q*. Think about [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: I am not able to understand with the hint given by you. Kindly explain little more. Thanks